# Angular ::ng-deep only for child component

Tags: css, angular-material, angular7

I would like to give margin-left to "mat-autocomplete-panel"

I'm using this **select-box component** in four different component. I would like to change 
**.mat-autocomplete-panel** margin only for one of them, and i don't want to effect others.

[image: Example of mat-autocomplete-panel]

So my question is basicly:

When i used following code all child components are affected but i would like to give margin left only one of them

```
::ng-deep .mat-autocomplete-panel {
  margin-left: -1200px;
}
```

I've tried following code as well but it didn't work.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-autocomplete-panel {
  margin-left: -1200px;
}
```

I've used cli ng g c  to creating all components and they're using .scss file i've changed them to .css but it didn't work as well.

Comment: try giving margin to one of the parent components or while using ng-deep try to give more spectfic path like ".parent .mat-autocomplete-panel"

Comment: Your answer is out of scope, i can override parent component actually but i don't want to do that. Because of if i override it all child components will be affected instead of doing it i need to override (not override edit actually) mat autocomplete panel for only a child component.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your autocomplete panel in some div, e.g.

```
<div class="autocomplete-wrapper">
   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" height="25">
        <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
 </div>
```

end then use this style:

```
:host .autocomplete-wrapper ::ng-deep .mat-autocomplete-panel  {
  margin-left: -1200px;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it. It didn't work didn't effect at all, thank you.